# Ground something, for a short time

Tags: grounding, switching

I need some simple solution, for grounding an AdKey for a short time lets say 200ms, only once, on each power on.

I don´t know the exact needed time so it would be nice if i can change the time with an resistor or so.
Till i found the right time.

I am using that circuit to power on/power off the load.

[image]

Is there a way to hold up the grounding from the on/off keypress a bit longer. becaus when i put the AdKey direct behind the on/off button. and u press the right time or make 2 short presses. It triggers. (The mcu take a bit time to bootup.)

Can that solution work?
[image]

So after 100ms or so the p-channel JFET(J1) should cuttoff,and stopping the ADKEY Ground.    In a couple days my hfet should arrive and i can tell more.

Big Thanks in front.

Comment: What is an AdKey?

Comment: an adkey is something like that http://www.astro-video.com/uploads/2/0/4/0/20407741/3501640_orig.jpg?446 ,   i think it stands for adaptive key.

Comment: What does it mean to "ground an AdKey"? How many pins need to be shorted to ground, what are the high and low voltage levels, and how much current will be passed to ground? You need to tell us what the AD_KEY signal is connected to.

Comment: i need to ground one pin the adkey to ground, when u ground it over 100k  ,u get the desired function. its on 3 volt so, 0.03 mA.

Comment: "Can that solution work?" - No. Because the FET will not *instantly* turn on or off. It will do so slowly in response to the slowly changing gate voltage.

Comment: @JimmyB so i need an schmitt trigger , or maybe a zener diode in front of the gate?

Comment: "when i put the AdKey direct behind the on/off button. and u press the right time or make 2 short presses. It triggers. (The mcu take a bit time to bootup.)" - Sorry, I don't understand what the problem is. What is supposed to happen when I press the button? How long/often am I supposed to press it?

Comment: one short press put the, latching circuit in on state.  when u press like 500ms the mcu is booted , and react to the Adkey ground command. When u press 2 short times  latching circuit is on , second press ground the adkey,but there is to much freedom.    What it should  one short or 500ms press latching circuit on and adkey grounded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something I like to do for reset circuits is a one-shot circuit. At least I think thats what it is called. It looks something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fctMuJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

V1 would be your supply voltage, and the output of the XOR is your "reset" signal. Basically, when your supply voltage starts to come up, the top input of the xor is high, and the RC circuit is charging up so it will be low. 10 gives a 1 on the output, so this signal is high until the RC circuit charges up. Once that happens, the output of the XOR goes low. The nice thing about this is that you can adjust your on time by fiddling with R1 and C1. Larger RC, larger time on. You can use this to power a fet, although I would suggest a gate driver of some kind as logic gates have super low current output.

Comment: Thanks, That solution will work. but it needs 4 parts.                                           Maybe there is an simpler solution for it?   Hope somebody knows one.

Comment: It doesn't get much simpler than an RC time constant... Are you using a microcontroller or have any type of existing control circuitry?

Comment: no i dont have one, my thinking now was using an RC circuit, in compination with an P-Channel Depletion-Mode mosfet . but there are nearly none.

Comment: Can´t i use a single p-channel mosfet . that when in on status shut itself down, via some sort of RC circuit.

Comment: So the circuit you've shown in your original post powers the AdKey directly? As in it is connected to the "5-18V Switched Power" node on the right side? And you want to ground it when you hit the On/Off button?

Comment: Right .when in on status it powers the device that has the adkey on it.  Yes it´s connected to switched power. Yes i want to ground it when u hit the on button, sadly the device doesn´t start up fast enough. to put it direct on the ONbutton.

Comment: Thanks, i will use that solution. can someone tells me what is better in an RC circuit? an high resistor or an high capacitator(from my understanding its better to take a high resistor?)  And do i need an ttl level XOR or cmos level XOR is enough?

Comment: @PhaseXavier You don't need an XOR at all. You basically only need a Schmitt-trigger input so that at some point the slowly rising voltage of the RC turns into a strong, binary output. So you can use a simple buffer like [CD4049UB](http://www.ti.com/product/CD4049UB#) (inverting) or CD4050B (non-inverting). Those chips contain six buffers each, you may be able to find smaller chips with less buffers since you only need one.

Comment: @JimmyB I´dont understand it, sorry. I need to ground the adkey for a short time. the device reacts when u stop grounding it. Holding it to long on ground and nothing happens. I think the simplest solution so far is in the question(when it works) the one with the p-channel jfet.

Comment: @PhaseXavier Notice that the XOR in the answer has one input connected to a constant high voltage. That just turns the XOR into an inverter for the RC. Might as well use a dedicated inverter. But do notice that you *must* use some part with Schmitt trigger inputs, else you will have intermediate voltages at the output as the RC voltage slowly rises.

Comment: @PhaseXavier What makes you think a JFET will act as a binary switch when its gate voltage slowly rises?

Comment: Hey cant i use an simply use an rc circuit on the gate of an p-mosfet. when i get the time period right?.                              I tried to get it work with an XOR the  74HCT86(ttl level) , but i think i need an 74HC86(cmos level)?

Answer (score 2):

There are special reset controllers / supervisors available which can be used for such a purpose.

E.g. NPC302 from ON Semiconductor [Datasheet](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/ncp302-d-1193929.pdf).

However, for the NPC302 you need an externally time delay generator.

TI also has such components [TI Supervisor - Reset IC category](http://www.ti.com/power-management/supervisor-reset-ic/products.html)

Comment: Nice, so i need only one part for the job  http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mcp809.pdf . As it puts the reset to low for 240ms, when voltage reaches a threshold. I think thats an real good solution. Somebody knows what happens to the reset pin after the 240ms. Is it dead than?

Comment: @PhaseXavier On page 4 of the datasheet you can see that the RESET pin will sink/source current during reset and source/sink current after that, so it stays active (high or low depending on the chip you select) at all times.

Comment: @JimmyB Thanks dump me so , i think i still need to control a mosfet with the reset pin. Because the Adkey needs to be free to react to other inputs(but maybe the source current(from the reset pin), is low enough to don´t mess with the adkey)             At my question, i wrote up another idea with an p channel jfet, that could work.  May someone take a look